Relationships between iterator and container in UML
I was constructing UML diagram for project at university and looking at the examples of others' diagrams I found that everyone, when it comes to iterators, shows the one-directional connection. Iterators contain pointer or reference to a container while this container at the same time uses this iterator or have it as a returning type of begin() and end() methods. As I can see that it's bidirectional connection (but I don't know which exactly because I'm bad at this) and I haven't seen anyone showing two arrows between container and iterator.
I believe if everyone does so then it's correct but I can't understand why. Where am I wrong?

Preliminary remark: Never assume that the majority necessarily means the truth. Take for example Galileo. Most of the people living on his time thought that the Sun turned around the Earth. He was the only one who told it was the opposite way, but it took a while for the world to realize that he was right. Likewise, there are still a lot of people thinking that aggregation is a useful notation when the current version of the UML specifications leave its semantics undefined.
The key in your problem is to realize that the relationship in both directions are of a different kind:

The container using the iterator is a usage dependency. In UML it is noted as a dashed line with an open arrow. It doesn't say anything about a permanence of the link.
The iterator knowing the container is an association.

Now regarding the association, the arrow from iterator to container means that the association is navigable, i.e. that at run time an iterator can easily find the linked container.
Most of the diagrams that I saw about iterators do not say anything about navigability in the opposite direction. That navigability is unspecified. If the navigation would be unidirectional only, the start of the arrow should be covered with a cross X.
Of course an association implies somewhat a dependency and it is in general avoided to display both at the same time.
